# unable to start gunicorn with fabric

Tags: python, fabric, gunicorn

My code lies in `/home/ubuntu/api` in the remote server. The WSGI object is named `app` and its present in `/home/ubuntu/api/api.py`. My gunicorn conf file is called `gunicorn.conf.py` and is present in `/home/ubuntu/api`

my `gunicorn.conf.py`

```
import multiprocessing

bind = "127.0.0.1:8000"
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
backlog = 2048
worker_class = 'gevent'
daemon = True
debug = True
loglevel = 'debug'
accesslog = '/mnt/log/gunicorn_access.log'
errorlog = '/mnt/log/gunicorn_error.log'
max_requests = 1000
graceful_timeout = 20
```

I am trying to start gunicorn on a server remotely through fabric. My fabric code looks like this

```
@roles('stag_api')
def run_server():
    with cd('/home/ubuntu/api'):
        sudo('gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py api:app')
```

Now fabric does not show any error but the gunicorn does not start.

So i created `__init__.py` in `/home/ubuntu/api` to make it a package. I wrote this in the `__init__.py` file

```
from api import app
```

This makes the WSGI `app` available in the package's namespace. Then i changed my fabric code to this

```
@roles('stag_api')
def run_server():
    sudo('gunicorn -c /home/ubuntu/api/gunicorn.conf.py api:app')
```

Even now fabric does not show any error but the gunicorn does not start.

So i created a shell script called `server` and its code looks like this

```
if [ "$1" = "start" ]; then
        echo 'starting'
        gunicorn -c /home/ubuntu/api/gunicorn.conf.py api:app
fi

if [ "$1" = "stop" ]; then
        echo 'stopping'
        pkill gunicorn
fi

if [ "$1" = "restart" ]; then
        echo 'restarting'
        pkill gunicorn
        gunicorn -c /home/ubuntu/api/gunicorn.conf.py api:app
fi
```

I place this shell script in `/home/ubuntu/api`

Now my fabric code looks like this

```
@roles('stag_api')
def stag_server(action='restart'):
    if action not in ['start', 'stop', 'restart']:
        print 'not a valid action. valid actions are start, stop and restart'
        return
    sudo('./server %s' % action)
```

Now when i try to start the server through fabric it print `starting` so the shell script is executing and the `if` block is reached but still i am not able to start the server through fabric.

But if i ssh to the server and do `sudo ./server start`, gunicorn starts.

Can someone explain what am i doing wrong?

Comment: provide error logs, please

Comment: @amezhenin there is no error. it just does not start gunicorn

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: Have you got the solution, I am in same situation and using pyt=False is also not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely related to these two FAQ points:

http://www.fabfile.org/faq.html#init-scripts-don-t-work

http://www.fabfile.org/faq.html#why-can-t-i-run-programs-in-the-background-with-it-makes-fabric-hang

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged (links tend to get broken over time). Please consider editing your answer and adding a synopsis here.

Comment: Thanks. adding `pty=False` works. So i changed my code to `sudo('./server %s' % action, pty=False)` and now it can successfully start guncorn. Please make your answer a little more descriptive.

Comment: @lovesh thank you! The links in the original answer no longer work. The closest I've found is http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.7/usage/interactivity.html but it doesn't discuss it in the context of init scripts or background processes.

Comment: Fixed the links, they got moved out of docs.fabfile.org for some reason. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting pty False globally with:

```
from fabric.api import env

env.always_use_pty = False
```

Or setting pty False for that command with:

```
run('run unicorn command etc...' pty=False)
```

See Init script section in:

http://www.fabfile.org/faq.html#init-scripts-don-t-work